Forward Voltage diode for a fixed current and different temperatures
I should measure forward voltages of a diode for different temperatures and a fixed current. I have a Keithley 2602A. Should I do a current source circuit?

It seems that series K-2602 are already a "source-meter". You just need a means to vary temperature...
